# How to verify 2 kinds of account?

Tags: java

Is it possible for the program to verify if the account credentials inputted by the user belongs to a certaing kind of account? if yes, how?
For example:

Database

```
username                      password
jake (admin)                   qwerty
anna (student)                 asdf
```

If the user inputted jake and qwerty as logon credentials then he would be able to access admin menus and when he used
student account anna and asdf then he'll be able to access student menus.

Logon Button:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    //str = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(this, "Enter id number: ");
    user = jTextField1.getText();
    pass = jPasswordField1.getPassword();
    login();
}
```

Function

```
private void login() {

    try {
        if ((user != null)&&(pass != null)) {
            sql = "Select * from users_table Where username='" + user + "' and password='" + pass + "'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
            if( rs.next()) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A basic JOptionPane message dialog");
            } else {
                //in this case enter when  result size is zero  it means user is invalid
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException err) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, err.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Comment: You could add a field to the "User"-table called: "Role" or "Rights" and return the given role by using a select.

Comment: Well, I could tell you that I could violate your security if I put a privileged username and for my pass placed "bla OR 1=1".  Use `PreparedStatement` to protect against that.

Answer (score 2):

Gian, it's typical to have some sort of "role" column in your user database.

For example:

```
username      password       role
jake          qwerty         admin
anna          asdf           student
```

When you get a result in your result set, read the "role" field from the table and make differences in functionality based on that.

```
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
        if( rs.next()) {
            if ("admin".equals(rs.getString("role")) {
                 // ...
            } else { 
                 // ...
            }
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "A basic JOptionPane message dialog");
        } else {
            //in this case enter when  result size is zero  it means user is invalid
        }
```

Good luck!

P.S. be aware of SQL injection attacks!! What could happen if I type username as follows? And how can you protect against it?

```
'; delete from users_table;
```

Comment: Roles really should be placed in a separate table, to support the very common case of user having multiple roles.